# Desktop PWA - Weird error banner with some URL when navigating

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-manifest

I try to make a desktop PWA for Chrome.
It works almost fine, but I have a problem.

My service worker is registered as below:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://subdomain.domain.ext/app/sw.js')
}
```

And my `webmanifest` contains only a `start_url` (no `scope`) as: `https://subdomain.domain.ext/app/monitoring/dashboard`

When I open my desktop PWA it works perfectly, when I navigate to pages like this one 
`https://subdomain.domain.ext/app/monitoring/**settings**`, it also works perfectly.

But when I navigate to pages like `https://subdomain.domain.ext/app/**marketing**/dashboard`, it works but I got a top banner as below.

[image: bug]

Do you have any idea what's going on and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Are you using actual asterisks in your path?

Comment: No of course. It was just to make differences clear. :-)